# Well Ordering Theorem Proof

Tags: set-theory

I've been going through a proof of Zermelo's Theorem, I need a small clarification, although the proof make sense anyway. Here is part of it
[image]

My question is about the very last step. It follows from the fact $T$ is in V that $\phi$ is well-ordered. I'm not sure if they mean under the inclusion order: I can see this means that every subset has a largest element, but not that it has a smallest element. I know this does define a well-order by just inverting the inclusion order on the set, but I don't know if that's what the proof is pointing at.

The fact you can define a well-order is clear and the rest of the proof makes sense anyway. I just want to make sure I'm not missing something that's more direct.

((Also, I've already posted another question on this particular proof before, so I apologise if this is pointlessly cluttering the site. I'll delete the question if necessary.))

Comment: There's no harm in asking two questions on the same proof. As long as you are not repeating the previous one, and you aren't repeating anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this defines a well-ordering using reverse-inclusion. The fact that this is a linear order is obvious (from the lemma).

Now let $T$ be the intersection of all those $S\in\phi$ such that every $V\in\scr V$ is a subset of $S$. Then if $T\in\scr V$ it is clearly the minimal element (in reverse inclusion) of $\scr V$ because it contains all the other members of $\scr V$.

Now the proof of the lemma gives a similar result here, if $T\notin\scr V$ then consider $T'$, it is either smaller than all those in $\scr V$ which is a contradiction to the choice of $T$, or it is not in $\scr V$. In the latter case note that the difference between the sets is one point, so not being in $\scr V$ means that it must really be incomparable with someone from $\scr V$, which is again a contradiction.

Comment: So just to be clear: the inclusion order in $\phi$ is not a well-ordering (at least it doesn't follow from what is done in the proof?

Comment: @Bleys: No, indeed it is the reverse inclusion which is a well-ordering on $\phi$. Also note that if an order *and* its inverse are well-orders then the set is finite. So most of the time the inclusion is not a well-order, but a reversed well-order.

Comment: Alright, thank you, Asaf! And thanks for the interesting note, I didn't know that.